# GCAL APIv3 events start time?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have been trying to play with Google calendar api v3. I have calendars and events listing no problem. However, I am trying to get certain data of events. I have `getSummary()` working and guessed `getLocation()`.

Does anyone know how to call the start time for an event? Are these functions listed anywhere that I am missing?

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
  //print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";

    $eventList = $cal->events->listEvents('yoyoyoyo@gmail.com');
    foreach($eventList->getItems()as $eventList){

        print "Name: ";
        echo $eventList->getSummary();
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        print "Start: ";
        echo $eventList->getdateTime(); <--- doesnt work hahah
        echo "<br/><br/><hr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, yes. Pretty much every google API of all time comes with a useful grouping of related documentation. You can in fact usually simply google "google [name your api here] documentation" and be led straight to it. The google calendar's main page has a link straight to their docs, too.
That's all for future reference. For now, you can probably paruse [this right here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events?hl=en)  and find what you're looking for- because right there in the first section I do indeed see a JSON return for "start" and "end" times. 
Good luck :)

Comment: HI I appreciate the response. I saw those docs but am not sure how to call a JSON return. I am a designer trying to prototype something. Ill do some google searches thanks ;)

Comment: If this solves your problem be sure to mark it as the best answer so others find it as well.

Comment: `code`$obj = json_decode($eventList);
print $obj->{"summary"};`code`

Comment: Trying to understand hwo to pull the array values out with JSON.

Comment: A few ideas:
1) Your foreach($eventList->getItems()as... there is no space between getItems() and 'as', which may be confusing the compiler (don't know)
2)You have the last 4 echo/print statements commented out, so that can't be helping.
You need to describe better what "doesn't work" means. What happens? Errors? What's SUPPOSED to happen? We can't compile your code so you have to do it for us and let us know with as much info as possible.

Comment: Look into decoding JSON in php using the json_decode() function. That should return an object that contains all of the data for you to access. Simply looping through the return of listEvents (which I assume is a string?) makes no sense. Use json_decode and just access the parameters through the object it gives you back.

Comment: Thanks Dudewad, I fixed the getItems()as. Ill explain better. I am successfully connected to my calendar and pulling events, I see about 30 results when using a function like getSummary(). This is where my code is at now. I can see the empty results from the horizontal rules but the array data, I cant seem to print to the page. `code` $eventList = $cal->events->listEvents('yoyoyo@gmail.com');
 foreach($eventList->getItems() as $eventList){
  
  $eventsData = json_decode($eventList);
  echo $eventsData->{"summary"};
  

  echo "<br/><br/><hr>";
 }
 `code`

Comment: Ok check this out. You're accessing the properties wrong, nothing more. Now, assuming that the value returned to $eventList IS INDEED a JSON string, you have 2 options for accessing it's data:
json_decode($eventList);
and json_decode($eventList, true);
The only difference between the two is that the first gives you an object, and the other gives you an associative array. i'd go with the object just cuz I'm a fan of objects over assoc arrays.
So, lets say $eventList is your JSON string:
$eventsData = json_decode($eventList);
echo $eventsData->summary;
echo $eventsData->start->date;
.....etc! :)

Comment: @user1710329 be sure to mark the answer as the correct answer!